# What to do with questions that are no-ops?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, close-reasons

Answering one's own question is A Good Thing, but what about when there is no value in the question or answer?

An example is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672493/android-textview-settext-is-appending-not-setting/6676171#6676171 where there is an underlying issue that isn't addressed in the original question, the OP solves the underlying issue, and answers the question with a general "turns out I xxx and there's no problem thanks for your time".

What if anything should be done about this? Personally, when I've asked a question that turns out to have an underlying cause, I've edited the question to explain what was going on and provided the resolution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like a perfect case for the "too localized" closing.

Comment: Good call. I guess I thought 'too localized' was too specific.

Comment: "Too localized" seems to suit those cases where the user reports he found what he did wrong, especially when the user is not adding an answer to report what he did to resolve the issue. Clearly, if the solution is, for example, to add a forgotten "#include" line which is clearly reported as necessary in the library documentation, then the question is still too localized.

Comment: Too localized is a perfect first step to deletion. These questions will never help anyone else in the future of the Interwebz, so there's just no use keeping them around. Ideally, the asker would delete them herself upon realizing her error. We all make mistakes.

Comment: I never really understood that closing reason. Good call.